# Concatenating data in visible rows within a named range to a string of desired format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data of `10 x 2` dimension. The data looks like below -

```
year     rate
05-06     10%
06-07     20.222%
07-08     13.17%
.
.
.
```

I want to print this data as a string within a text box present over the chart object and the format of the first column must be a text and the format of the second column must be truncated to one decimal place with a percent symbol. I have concatenated the data as string and pasted it to the text box object over the chart by mapping the cell containing the formula calling the function below.

The string format should look like below -

```
05-06 : 10.0% ; 06-07 : 20.2% ; 07-08 : 13.2% ...
```

I have stored this data as a named range `rateCurrent` and I have used the below code to generate the string of visible rows.

```
= ConcatenateVisible(rateCurrent, ":", ";")
```

For time being, assume I have pasted the data starting at column 3, row 8.

```
Function ConcatenateVisible(rng As Variant, seperator As String, separator1 As String)
    For Each cll In rng
        If cll.EntireRow.Hidden = False And rng.Column = 3 Then
        Debug.Print rng.Row
            ConcatenateVisible = ConcatenateVisible & Format(cll.Value, "@") & seperator
            Debug.Print cll.Value
        Else
        Debug.Print rng.Row
            ConcatenateVisible = ConcatenateVisible & Format(cll.Value, "0.0%") & seperator1
        End If
    Next
    ConcatenateVisible = Left(ConcatenateVisible, Len(ConcatenateVisible) - Len(seperator))
End Function
```

For some reason, the second loop is not working and I am receiving the output like below -

```
05-06 : 10.00000000000 : 06-07 : 20.2222222222 : 07-08 : 13.1765433333 ....
```

I tried the below function as well which, when added the if loop for format breaks -

```
Public Function MakeList(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
On Error GoTo Errhand:

    Dim c       As Range
    Dim MyDict  As Object: Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To myRange.Cells.Count
        For Each c In myRange
            If Not Rows(c.Row).Hidden Then
                If Not MyDict.exists(c.Value2) Then MyDict.Add c.Value2, 1
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print c, MyDict.keys

        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            MakeList = Join(MyDict.keys, ": ")
        Else
            MakeList = Join(MyDict.keys, "; ")
        End If
    Next
cleanExit:
    Set MyDict = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing
    Exit Function

Errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    GoTo cleanExit
End Function
```

Any hints or help or suggestions are much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Function concatenateVisible(rng As Range, Optional separator As String = " : ", _
    Optional separator1 As String = " ; ") As String

    Dim rw As Range
    Dim str As String

str = ""
For Each rw In rng.Rows
    If rw.Hidden = False And Len(rw.Cells(1, 1)) > 0 Then
        str = str & separator1 & _
            rw.Cells(1, 1) & separator & Format(rw.Cells(1, 2), "0.0%")
    End If
Next rw

concatenateVisible = Mid(str, Len(separator1))

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I was missing the `.cells(rows, cols)` all along!

Comment: @xkcvk2511 Note that, among other things, there's no need to format the "year" input as text.